# Executing methods of specific page in JAVA/SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am currently trying to run a code and when I run it I get a "this.driver" is null error.
I have tried to invoke the driver through its address in the page, but to no avail.
I also tried to play a bit with the elements to make sure every element indeed exists in the website with the locators I used.

this is the page code:

```
   public class FlightDetailsPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    //using the PageFactory method
    public FlightDetailsPage (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements (driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(css = "input[value='oneway']")
    WebElement oneWayRadio;


    Select passengersSelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='passCount']")));

    Select departFromSelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ( "select[name='fromPort']")));

    Select departMonthSelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='fromMonth']")));

    Select departDaySelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='fromDay']")));

    Select arriveInSelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='toPort']")));

    Select returningMonthSelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='toMonth']")));

    Select returningDaySelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='toDay']")));

    @FindBy(css = "input[value='Business']")
    WebElement businessClassRadio;

    @FindBy(css = "input[value='First']")
    WebElement firstClassRadio;

    Select airlineSelect = new Select (driver.findElement (By.cssSelector ("select[name='airline']")));

    @FindBy(css = "input[name='findFlights']")
    WebElement continueButton;

    public void firstRadioCheck(){
        oneWayRadio.click ();
    }

    public void passengerCounter(int From_0_To_3){
        passengersSelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_3);
    }

    public void departFrom(int From_0_To_9){
        departFromSelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_9);
    }

    public void departingMonth(int From_0_To_11){
        departMonthSelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_11);
    }

    public void departingDay(int From_0_To_30){
        departDaySelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_30);
    }

    public void arrivalPlace(int From_0_To_8){
        arriveInSelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_8);
    }

    public void returnDay(int From_0_To_30){
        returningDaySelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_30);
    }

    public void returnMonth(int From_0_To_11){
        returningMonthSelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_11);
    }

    public void businessRadioOptionCheck(){
        businessClassRadio.click ();
    }

    public void firstClassOptionCheck(){
        firstClassRadio.click ();
    }

    public void airlineSelector(int From_0_To_3){
        airlineSelect.selectByIndex (From_0_To_3);
    }

    public void nextPage(){
        continueButton.click ();
    }

    public void checkTheForm(){
        firstRadioCheck ();
        passengerCounter (1);
        departFrom (2);
        departingMonth (10);
        departingDay (14);
        arrivalPlace (3);
        returnDay (5);
        returnMonth (1);
        businessRadioOptionCheck ();
        firstClassOptionCheck ();
        airlineSelector (2);
        nextPage ();
    }

}
```

and this is the error stack:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58099:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Eden\IdeaProjects\OlgaProject\target\classes;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.141.59\selenium-java-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.141.59\selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.141.59\selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.141.59\selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.141.59\selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.141.59\selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.141.59\selenium-support-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Eden\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar Main
1622477608296   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:10599
1622477608528   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Eden\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile1lPO8r"
1622477609095   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
1622477611446   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 58345
1622477611718   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
May 31, 2021 7:13:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1622477614990   Marionette  WARN    Ignoring event 'DOMContentLoaded' because document has an invalid readyState of 'complete'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
    at Pages.FlightDetailsPage.<init>(FlightDetailsPage.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any idea why this.driver would be null?

Comment: Could you try to initialize the Selects in the constructor like the driver itself.

Comment: Where / how are you passing a WebDriver driver to the `FlightDetailsPage` class constructor?

Comment: hey the driver is provoked in the Main method

Comment: System.setProperty ("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Desktop\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
        driver.manage ().timeouts ().implicitlyWait (10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage ().window ().maximize ();
        driver.navigate ().to ("http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/");

Comment: Please add this into the question body. It's not readable as comment

Comment: Problem solved when moving the Select elements into the constructor.